# Equivalent of "jade blocks" in handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, pug

Does handlebars have equivalent functionality to [jade blocks](http://www.devthought.com/code/use-jade-blocks-not-layouts/)?
I understand that it has *partials* but I don't see how I can imitate jade's block functionality with just partials.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish with jade:
**Master template:**

```
// layout.jade
doctype 5
html
head
  title= title
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  block head

body
  header
    block header

  block content

  footer
    block footer

  block scripts
```

**Other template:**

```
// camera.jade
extends layout

block head
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/camera.css')

block header
  h1 Camera

block content
  section#secScreen
    video#vdoScreen
    aside#asdControls
      nav
        a(href='/') Back
        a(href='') Refresh
        a(href='/gallery') Gallery

block scripts
  script(src='/javascripts/camera.js')
```

I found this module called [handlebars-layouts](https://github.com/shannonmoeller/handlebars-layouts) by [shannonmoeller](https://github.com/shannonmoeller) that seems to add this feature, to handlebars.
This seems like an alright module but I'd like to know if there's another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do **without installing another dependency?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not currently, which is why I made [handlebars-layouts](https://github.com/shannonmoeller/handlebars-layouts). If you don't like managing multiple plugins, there's a derivative layouts helper in the excellent [handlebars-helpers](https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers) collection with over a hundred other helpers.